# Sort Date Dimensions By Custom Financial Years in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to sort the week and month column below (Week Ending Date)according to FY as currently, months are in alphabetical order.

```
YearWeek ReportDate              Work order Week Ending Date FinancialYrSort
202135   22/08/2022 12:00:00 AM  WO7094852  28/08/2022       2
202202   3/01/2022  12:00:00 AM  WO7465604  9/01/2022        1
202201   27/12/2021  12:00:00 AM WO7690126  2/01/2022        6
202153   26/12/2022  12:00:00 AM WO7467312  1/01/2023        6
202130   18/07/2022  12:00:00 AM WO6947586  24/07/2022       1
```

[image]
I've created the Financial Yr Sort column to be used for sorting -

```
Financial Yr Sort = If(MONTH('22a Planned Maintenance Efficiency'[reportDate]) > 6, MONTH('22a Planned Maintenance Efficiency'[Week Ending Date]) - 6, MONTH('22a Planned Maintenance Efficiency'[reportDate] + 6))
```

This generates July months from No 1 and goes on.
When I try to sort Weekending dates by Financial year an error message pops up. Please see the 2nd picture.
[image]

Can someone help me to sort this out?
Please note I want show the line graph by week. Please refer to the 3rd picture.
[image]

Comment: why you dont use yearweek from your table (first visible column from your screenshot)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Year week is from Jan to Dec. The financial year is from Jul to Jun. Users want to see weeks in "MMMM-DD" format.

Comment: I still don't understand why not sort by yearWeek. In Powerbi, from the list on the right, select the column you present on the chart. At the top of Column tools, expand "Sort by column" and select yearWeek.

Comment: Himsta42a, Please apologise for not being clear enough in the first place. My answer is in the 2nd comment below as it exceeds the limit of character number.

Comment: Currently, the week ending column is sorted by default by the year Week column. "yerWeek" column starts from Jan, so the first week of Jan is week 1 and the last week in Dec is the 52nd week. Again in 2022 1st week of Jan starts as week no 1. Our financial year is from Jul to Jun. So the financial week number I is the first week of July. Until the end of December, we didn't have any problem sorting the column Week Ending Date by yearWeek. But from Jan 22, January details are shown before the July details in the line graphs. We want to show the week MMMM-DD format without the year.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data in tabular form that I could use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi msta42a, thanks a lot for helping me. I tried to edit the comment and provide sample data in tabular form. Not sure it worked. It comes as just one raw. So I thought to insert a picture of the same data. Please refer to my 1st comment. I also noticed my Financial yr Sort Dax gives erroneous results. This is the formula I used -    Financial Yr Sort = If(MONTH('22a Planned Maintenance Efficiency'[reportDate]) > 6, MONTH('22a Planned Maintenance Efficiency'[reportDate]) - 6, MONTH('22a Planned Maintenance Efficiency'[reportDate] + 6))